# regex expression optimisation

Tags: regex

What is the best way to make the following regex statement?

```
\\t(?P<event_code>47(2[0-9]|3[0-5]|3[7-8]|([4-5][0-9]|6[1-2]|6[4-7])|8[0-1]|8[3-9]|9[0|4])|537[6|7])\\
```

I am searching windows event logs for certain event numbers:

```
4720-4735
4737-4738
4740-4762
4764-4767
4780-4781
4783-4790
4794
5376-5377
```

In the string they are enclosed by `/t` and `/` and the result must be no more and no less than 4 digits.

Here is an example of the text that I search into:

```
17 Nov 2020 15:24:07.809{
  "timestamp": "2020-11-17T03:24:06.000Z",
  "source_user": "source user",
  "target_user": "traget user",
  "source_user_domain": "source.domain",
  "target_user_domain": "destination.domain",
  "action": "PASSWORD_RESET",
  "source_account": "source account",
  "target_account": "target account",
  "source_data": "<14>Nov 17 05:24:06 domain controller MSWinEventLog\t1\tSecurity\t3257313\tTue Nov 17 05:24:06 2020\t4723\tMicrosoft-Windows-Security-Auditing\tN/A\tN/A\tSuccess Audit\tdomaincontroller\tUser Account Management\t\tAn attempt was made to reset an account's password.    Subject:   Security ID:  SID   Account Name:  account name   Account Domain:  account domain   Logon ID:  ID    Target Account:   Security ID:  SID   Account Name:  account name   Account Domain:  account domain"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things can be refactored.

In example, `3[0-5]|3[7-8]` can be simplified to `3[0-57-8]`

Note that `9[0|4]` will be evaluated as `9` followed by either `0`, `|` or `4`

A refactored RegEx looks like this :

```
(47(2[0-9]|3[0-57-8]|[4-5][0-9]|6[1-24-7]|8[0-13-9]|9[04]))|(537[67])
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7pNrd/2)